# Xamarin form: improve text search performance

Tags: listview, xamarin, search

How do improve the performance when doing the text searching using search bar and listview?

```
public ICommand OnTextChangedCommand 
    {
        get 
        {
            return new Command((obj) => 
            { 
                if (obj is TextChangedEventArgs)
                {
                    var arg = obj as TextChangedEventArgs;

                    var matchedChildren = new ObservableCollection<SignInOutViewModel>(cachedCopy.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(arg.NewTextValue) || x.DisplayName.Contains(arg.NewTextValue)).ToList());
                    Collection = matchedChildren;

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.NewTextValue))
                        Collection = new ObservableCollection<SignInOutViewModel>(cachedCopy);
                    else
                    {
                        var words = arg.NewTextValue.ToLower().Split(' ');
                        Collection = new ObservableCollection<SignInOutViewModel> (cachedCopy.Where(x =>
                        {
                            var isContain = false;
                            foreach (var word in words)
                            {
                                isContain = x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(word);
                            }
                            return isContain;
                        }).ToList());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I replaced the whole list after search each characters. I know it would be performance issue when the list are big to search. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you actually done any testing to determine where the perf problem is in your algorithm?  The first thing I notice is that the two lines starting with "var matchedChildren..." are apparently never used.  That's wasted cycles.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you create a new `Command` each time the text changes, which you don't need to do. You can move the `Action` that is given as a parameter for the `new Command()` into its own private function. Then you can create a private variable `ICommand _onTextChangedCommand`, and in this class' constructor, you can say `_onTextChangeCommand = new Command(MySearchFunction)`, and then simply return `_onTextChangeCommand` in the `OnTextChangeCommand`'s getter.

Comment: Oh sorry ignore the matchChildren line... Yes i did use this on one application. It would be ok if the item in the listview only show simple text with one icon. If item in listview contain complex ui, performance issue will exist.